# Expectation of discretized (ceiling) normal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

For given $\mu,\sigma$, I would like to get an expression for the expectation of a discretized normal, specifically $E(\lceil N(\mu,\sigma^2)\rceil)$.

I know how to write the infinite sum, but that does not help me analyze the expectation.
I'm interested in (i) a closed form expression or (ii) if it's not possible, an approximation.
For (ii), I'm in a setting where the std is not large, say $\sigma\leq \mu$.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's an easy closed form expression unless I'm missing something. I'll just put the infinite sum here in case anyone has an insight.

$$\sum_{z\in \mathbb Z} z \{\Phi(z, \mu, \sigma^2)-\Phi(z-1, \mu, \sigma^2)\}$$

where $\Phi(z, \mu, \sigma^2)$ is CDF of $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ evaluated at $z$.